# How to stop shoes from squeaking on hard floors?

Tags: shoes

I have a pair of pretty nice shoes that I love, except when I'm going to work!

We have hard linoleum-style flooring in most places, and carpet only in the office area where I work. When I have to go to another area, my shoes squeak **very loudly**.

I have tried [other sources of information](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=242383) for this problem, but to no avail. The squeak is coming from the shoe to the ground; I tested this by taking my insoles out and walking, and the squeak was still there. My shoes are thoroughly dry, and there are no rocks or things stuck between the few lines it has on the bottom.

The warranty period has passed, and I only started recently wearing them more than once a month.

**What can I do to stop the squeaking, and annoying co-workers?**

Comment: What are the treads of your shoe like? Basketball and tennis shoes tend to squeak on  hard floors, because they have lots of ridges.

Comment: Dressy shoes, but not like Oxford shoes

Answer (score 10):

One option could be to add an extra layer of rubber on your soles. There exists [rubber sole spray](//google.com/search?q=rubber+sole+spray) which are made for either fixing soles, giving better traction to soles, improve winter shoes, and so on. This extra layer would most likely remove the squeaking.

Just to verify that it is actually the outer soles which are squeaking, you could try adding duct tape to the bottom of the shoes, and see if that is a doable quick-fix. If it does fix it, look around for either a local shoe repair shop or go online and see if you can't find a suitable rubber sole spray.

*PS!* Have you tried asking at your local shoe repair shop if they have any suggestions? Advice is often free, you know

Answer (score 5):

The soles of some shoes are covered with a thin layer of black paint to make them look shiny and new. That's what is making your shoes squeak. You have two options, wear the shoes until this layer is worn off or get some sandpaper and get scrubbing. It's only a thin layer and you will see it peeling off as you sand them, so don't go nuts. Once this layer is gone, no more squeak! You'll have better grip on wet floors too.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to stop rubber soles from squeaking due to the "gription" on a floor is to rub a bar of soap on the sole. The cheaper the bar, the better it works. Just a pass or two in the sole and you're done. One might think that it would make the shoe slippery but it does not. It actually improves traction.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly have never had this problem. Ever. But if I did, I think the first thing I would try would to make the bottom of my shoe less slick(perfect). It seems to me that two slick surfaces squeak way more than one that is slick and one that is a little rougher.

I would think a cheap, FINE grained sandpaper for just a couple of seconds on the bottom of the shoe should do it. I would be careful not to take the whole sole of the shoe off, that would be sad. :)

Answer (score 2):

When a shoe starts making squeaking noises, this is because two parts of the shoe are rubbing against each other and sticking, when they should be sliding smoothly.

Thus, lubricant of some form is called for. A quick Google search tells me that baby powder and WD-40 are both recommended for this job, though I'm sure plenty of other lubricants would work just fine.

First, identify what part of the shoe the squeaking noises are coming from. Next, apply lubricant, work it in, and you're done. If it is underneath the sole of the shoe, make sure to lift up the sole before applying the lubricant.

Edit: Make sure to wipe any leftover lubricant off of the bottom of your shoe so your shoe doesn't lose any traction.

Comment: "If it's loose and should be fix, use duct tape. In any other case, use WD-40. "
- old proverb

Comment: Some of those links also says that it is not going to last very long, some say just for a few foot steps. In addition, this applies to squeaking inbetween the inner sole and the shoe. OP tried walking with the shoe, without the inner sole, and it still squeaked. In other words, this answer doesn't apply to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try spraying any type of oil on the bottom of the shoes and leave it there for a few hours then wipe it off. (Be careful you might slip due to the oil)

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that the floor cleaner I use on my hard floors make the rubber soles on my shoes squeak.  When I spray the soles of my shoes with WD40 and wipe away the excess, the squeak goes away.  Although this fix is temporary, it is the only thing I have found that helps.  In the meantime, I am looking for a floor cleaner that won't cause my rubber soled shoes to squeak.

Answer (score 1):

I have two pairs of shoes that make so much noise on the tile floor at work that my co-workers make jokes about them. 
I tried the soap - took a small bar (hotel size, actually hotel-supplied), unwrapped it,  and just rubbed the bar all over the bottom of the sole, with some extra emphasis on worn spots.  Ninja quiet now.  I keep the bar in my desk drawer. smells good, and works great.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that a five minute dip in pure bleach about 1/2 inch deep for 5-10 minutes will soften and cure the problem then rinse in warm water, just the soles now! I am going to try this in a few minutes and Dr. Ralph will get back to you soon.

Comment: Updates? Video? Pictures?

Comment: Won't that destroy the shoes? Is this a prank answer?

Comment: "I am going to try this in a few minutes and Dr. Ralph will get back to you soon." --- How soon?