# New shoes squeaking

Tags: shoes

I grabbed a brand new pair of Lacoste Carnaby Evo's, only wear them on special occasions which has been twice so far.

But on my 3rd wear, I noticed that my shoe started to squeak. It was significantly wet when I wore them the last time so I tried baking soda (since I had no baby powder) and placed them in the drying rack for a whole 24 hrs. But still squeaking, I tried to wear it without the insole and it turned out that it still sounded. So I think it's the outsole that's making the sound.

I tried sanding the bottom, but still no luck.

Any tips to get rid of the squeak?

Comment: Many tips [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/how-to-stop-shoes-from-squeaking-on-hard-floors). Anything that works for you?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a pair of shoes, and it turned out to be a manufacturing defect - they used a glue that would unstick when wet, causing a squeak (it actually sounded more like a duck quacking). The only thing I found that worked was replacing the shoes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop shoes from squeaking on hard floors?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/how-to-stop-shoes-from-squeaking-on-hard-floors)

Comment: @SethMMorton Contacted the place I bought them from and got a replacement (still being delivered). Hope the new ones don't squeak again.

Comment: @AJ not sure this is a dupe, based on the question and comment from OP, the sound is not floor type dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate where the squeaky noise is coming from by walking slowly, rocking back and forth and raising your heels. When you've located the squeak, sprinkle that specific area with cornstarch, baby powder or baking powder. ... If your shoes are lined with non-removable insoles, rub the powder into the edge of the shoe base.